# route-me image overlay in iPhone

Tags: image, maps, overlay, tiles, route-me

I'm using route-me in my project. Library is quite good. Adding markers, drawing polygone work fine. How about placing single image as overlay in given location (latitude, longitude)?  This funcionality is missing I think. Has anyone done placing the image overlay without overloading the tiles source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution...

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D lcA =   CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(oSector.f_overlay_lat_min,oSector.f_overlay_long_min);
        CLLocationCoordinate2D lcB = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(oSector.f_overlay_lat_max,oSector.f_overlay_long_max);

        CGPoint cgA = [mvMap latLongToPixel:lcA];
        CGPoint cgB = [mvMap latLongToPixel:lcB];

        float fLatMin  = MIN(cgA.x,cgB.x);
        float fLongMin = MIN(cgA.y,cgB.y);

        float fWidth  = sqrt((cgA.x - cgB.x)*(cgA.x - cgB.x));
        float fHeight = sqrt((cgA.y - cgB.y)*(cgA.y - cgB.y));

        RMMapLayer *mlLayer = [[RMMapLayer alloc] init];
        mlLayer.contents = (id) oSector.im_overlay.CGImage;
        mlLayer.frame    = CGRectMake(fLatMin,fLongMin,fWidth,fHeight); 

        [[mvMap.contents overlay] addSublayer:mlLayer];
```

the mvMap is IBOutlet RMMapView *mvMap somewhere in your h file

the oSector.im_overlay.CGImage can be

```
UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:<something>];
lmLayer.contents = i.CGImage
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an RMMarker?   You can apply any image you want to it and place it as needed.   Even make it draggable if you want to:

```
UIImage *imgLocation = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile :
                          [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"location_ind"      
                                                          ofType:@"png"]];
markerCurrentLocation = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:imgLocation];
// make sure it is always above everything else.
markerCurrentLocation.zPosition = -1.0;
[mapView.markerManager addMarker:markerCurrentLocation
                       AtLatLong:startingPoint];
```

Ciao!

-- Randy